# XML sax parse exception. Invalid content error

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

This is my Xml

```
  <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:ch="http://abc.def.com/admin/find/types/v1" 
           targetNamespace="http://abc.def.com/admin/find/types/v1"
         elementFormDefault="qualified" >

         <import namespace="http://esi.osm.com/commonheader/v3" schemaLocation="CommonHeaderV3_3.xsd" />
    ...  
        <xsd:complexType name="SystemConfig">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <element name="System"      type="xsd:int"        minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="NetworkType" type="ch:NetworkType" minOccurs="1" />
                <element name="Location"    type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="Address"     type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="0" />
                <element name="City"        type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>

       <simpleType name="NetworkType" >
            <restriction base="string">
                <enumeration value="CABLE" />
                <enumeration value="DSL" />
            </restriction>
       </simpleType>
```

The error I got when I attempted to run my web service is this..

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ns3:Location'. One of '{"http://abc.def.com/admin/find/types/v1":NetworkType}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
```

Edit:
Java code

```
    NetworkType networkType= null;
        if(db.getNetworkType().equals("cable")) {
            networkType= NetworkType.fromValue("CABLE");
        } 
        if (db.getNetworkType().equals("dsl")) {
            networkType = NetworkType.fromValue("DSL");
        } 
   ntList.setNetworkType(networkType);
   log.info(networkType); //prints null....
```

The values that printed for networkType is null but actually i was able to get the db values
Actually I found the problem....there are white spaces contained in the db so the values passed are not entirely correct. 
It ran fine after trim() was added

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your XML, from the error message alone it's clear that the parser encountered a `ns3:Location` element, realized that a preceding, *required* `ch:NetworkType` element was not found, and complained about the omission.   We can tell that `ch:NetworkType` is required because your XSD fragment has `minOccurs="1"` on `ch:NetworkType` in the content model for `SystemConfig`.

Comment: I just noticed my java code that the networktype was null but the value from db is not null